# Why does a call to a service deployed to a server not return a Problem Details object?

Tags: c#, rest, http-status-code-404

I have a service (call it B) that my service (call it A) calls to get data.  It provides a GUID identifier for the lookup.  If the service fails to find the information, it returns a Problem Details object with a 404 status.

```
{
"type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.4",
"title": "Not Found",
"status": 404,
"traceId": "8000278f-0000-9d00-b63f-84710c7967bb"
}
```

I can run my service locally, call service B and I get the expected results.  I can use Swagger UI on service B that is deployed to the development server and get the expected results.

However, when my service is deployed to the development server and the call is executed for service B, I get the following.

```
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

That is literally what it returns.  It's not in a problem details object.  This then leads to a JSON parsing error.

I am at a loss as to why it does this on the server but not locally.  Has this happened to anyone else?  What did you do to solve it?  Is there some sort of IIS setting that would cause this?

Thanks for your input.

Comment: If you need some help you have to post the code of both services.

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to be a configuration error.  During deployment, the correct URL was being set in the appsettings.json file.  However, the URL did not end in a / character.  This resulted in an incorrect URL pointing to a non-existent resource.  Thus the error in plain text.  I corrected this by ensuring that a URL being read in from the config file ends in a / character.

The reason it worked locally is that the URL was set with the trailing '/' character.  Deployment derives the URL by reading an environment settings file and then sets the values based on what it finds.